# update image on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, updates, crud

> I'm stuck from make a update image from codeigniter, i want replace image when i update it but, the code its doesn't work.
> here is my code :
>
> **this is Controller :**

```
public function updatefoto(){
     $this->load->model('model_users');
    $this->model_users->updatefoto();

}
```

> **This is The Model**

```
public function updatefoto($userId){

    if($this->input->post('submit')){
         $config['upload_path']    = "./uploads/images/";
         $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
         $config['max_size']       = '2000';
         $config['max_width']      = '2000';
         $config['max_height']     = '2000';
         $config['file_name']      = 'gambar-'.trim(str_replace(" ","",date('dmYHis')));
         $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload("gambar")) {
             $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>','</div>'));

            $this->load->view('view_ubah_data-profile', $error);
        }else{
           $nama=$this->upload->data('file_name');
           $this->db->where('id', $userId);
           $this->db->update('foto',array('nama_foto'=>$nama));
           
           redirect('view_ubah_data-profile','refresh');
        }
       }
   }
```

> **and the last is view**

```
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <form action="users/updatefoto" method="post" id="updateUserImage">
          <div class="text-center">

            <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/images/<?php echo $userData['nama_foto']  ?>" cclass="img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">
            <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>
            <input type="file" class="text-center center-block well well-sm" name="gambar" id="files" accept="image/*" required>
            <button type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>upload
          </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

> Thanks I appreciate any help :)

Comment: Update the image in controller not in model

Comment: Please follow https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: @MalikMudassar i'm want to update image not insert/upload image/

Comment: same method will be used whether you update or insert new. To update an image, display the last image , keep the id, delete that if you want by some control like button. or just upload another image using the same code but in the model function where you save the image name in the database just replace it with the old one and unlink the old file to delete it from server

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it.

**Edit- Class Construct**

```
class Team extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->model('team_model');
 }


 public function do_upload()
 {
    $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size']             = 100;
    $config['max_width']            = 1024;
    $config['max_height']           = 768;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile1'))
    {
        $data['errors'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $data['client_Id']=$this->team_model->getUserId($email);
        $data['pic']=$this->team_model->getImage($data['client_Id']['id']);
        // Here I load my Views
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
        $file_name=$upload_data['file_name'];
        $email=$this->session->userdata['email'];
        $data['client_Id']=$this->team_model->getUserId($email);
        $data['pic']=$this->team_model->getImage($data['client_Id']['id']);
        // If there is no image insert one other wise update
        if($data['pic']['image']!=''){
            $this->team_model->updateEmployeeImage($data['pic']['id'],$file_name);
            $data['success']='Congratulations! Image Updated Successfully';
        }else{
            $this->team_model->InsertEmployeeImage($data['client_Id']['id'],$file_name);
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $data['success']='Congratulations! Image Uploaded Successfully';
        }
        $file_name=$upload_data['file_name'];
        $email=$this->session->userdata['email'];
        $data['client_Id']=$this->team_model->getUserId($email);
        $data['pic']=$this->team_model->getImage($data['client_Id']['id']);

        // Here I load my Views
    }
 }
}
```

**Edit- Model Functions**

```
public function InsertEmployeeImage($id,$image){
    $Image=array(
        'id'                    => '',
        'team_id'             => $id,
        'image'                 => $image
    );
    $this->db->insert('teams_image',$Image);
    return ;
}

public function updateEmployeeImage($id,$img){
     $this->deleteOldImage($id);
     $pic=array(
        'image'      =>  $img
    );
    $this->db->WHERE('id',$id)->update('teams_image',$pic);
}
```

Comment: and this function is in my controller

Comment: @Firm Model functions should be used to interact with database, send data to and get data from database. Rest of the stuff we do in Controller.

Comment: if you can see I am calling team_model functions for different things like getting client details from his Email etc

Comment: in the IF statement you can see i am calling team_model functions updateEmployeeImage() and InsertEmployeeImage() these two functions are in my model . So I am using models but not for uploading image but for storing the data to database and getting it back

Comment: so is that right from your code, the id from the photo is email? can i see your team_model?

Comment: no, photo has its name, which is stored in the user_images or client_images table. the images table has a foreign key like user_id or client_id which links it to entity

Comment: deleteOldImage() function gets the url of old image and unlink it

Comment: i just confuse, why that you do this "$data['client_Id']=$this->team_model->getUserId($email);", and it your field name of id image is "id"?

Comment: oh, the session has email in it and the image table has Id in it so to get client id , i wrote a function which gets his email as a parameter and returns his id. :) you can ignore this line